# Assign dynamic key string in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I wanto do something like this, is it possible in python.

```
f = 'free'
p = 'paid'
if version is f:
      APP_VER = 'APP_FREE'
elif version is p:
      APP_VER = 'APP_PAID'

s_email = webapp2.get_app().config[APP_VER]['SUPPORT_EMAIL']

Error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'APP_VER' referenced before assignment
```

Any idea!

Comment: Don't check string equality with `is` use `==`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if version is f:
      APP_VER = 'APP_FREE'
elif version is p:
      APP_VER = 'APP_PAID'
```

there is a possibility `version` is neither `f` nor `p`. Include an `else` part. Also (as @jamylak notes) use `==` to compare strings, not `is`:

```
if version == f:
      APP_VER = 'APP_FREE'
elif version == p:
      APP_VER = 'APP_PAID'
else:
    print 'version <{0}> unknown'.format(version)
    exit()
    # or raise an exception here
```

Another way (great improvement if the list of versions is longer):

```
app_name = {'free': 'APP_FREE',
            'paid': 'APP_PAID'} # this can be extended if needed
APP_VER = app_name.get(version)
# APP_VER is None if version unknown
```